# Linux CentOs7 hidden files

Tags: centos, disk-usage

I have a Linux CentOs7 server, 
The server parition `dev/mapper/centos-root/`size is `80GB`
When I run `df` I can see that 58 GB are in use.

[image]

When I do `du -shx *` I see that there is more or less 28GB space taken by data
[image]

Where are the remaining 30gb gone?
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: I find it strange that several directories have 0 size, e.g. `bin`. That doesn't make sense. `lib` and `lib64` most definitely have something in them, including `bin`.

Comment: Aren't /bin and and /sbin just symlinks to like /usr/bin and /usr/sbin? That's the way it is on my Manjaro and $ du -shx * shows 0 for them indeed.

Comment: Most likely any difference between du and df is the result of files that are deleted but still open. Can you reboot?  If not, look into ‘lsof’ to find deleted files open by running processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ncdu` for visualize hd usage.

`ncdu` is the "ncursers du", so you need to have ncurses lib if you want to compile the code your self.

Be sure to run the tool as root, cause some file will be only visible to the root user.